# Is there any equivalent C/C function of IdnMapping::GetAscii C# Methode?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-ce

I'm trying to implement a C# code into C/C++ in Wince 6.0 (without installing of .NET Framework).

in this C# code, the methode IdnMapping::GetAscii is used, which needs to be also converted in C/C++.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.idnmapping.getascii.aspx

an eqıivalent fonction to IdnMapping::GetAscii is needed..

thnx for tipps and helps =)

regards..

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

1. Getting length of string
2. Initialize a new Unicode String with the pointer on the first element of your input
3. Foreach sign in your string make a static_cast and copy this to your ASCII-string

   char* GetASCII(const wchar_t* wstr)
   {
       int count = wcslen(wstr);
       char* ascii = new char[count + 1];

   ```
   wchar_t* pwchr = const_cast<wchar_t*> (&wstr[0]);

   for(int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
   {
      ascii [j] = static_cast<char> (*pwchr);
      pwchr++;
   } 
   ascii [count] = '\0';
   return ascii ;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

The "ascii" string is in punycode.

So you need to look for sample code for punycode conversion, for example, https://www.example-code.com/cpp/punycode.asp

Comment: For an idnMapping the 'ascii' string is not a simple "cast", but get's the A-label from the U-label.